# Как организовать доступ из Maven-проекта к зависимости, которая постоянно модифицируется и находится в другой директории?

Tags: java, maven

Предположим, что Maven-проекты `Project1` (допустим, находящийся в `D:\IntelliJ_IDEA\Project1\src\main\java\dev\example1\Main.java`) и `Project2` (находится `D:\IntelliJ_IDEA\Project2\src\main\java\dev\example2\Main.java`) используют библиотеку в стадии разработки `Library` (находится в `D:\IntelliJ_IDEA\Library\src\main\java\dev\example3\Main.java`). Другими словами, все проекты находятся в разных директориях и имеют разные репозитории. По ходу написания `Project1` и `Project2`, `Library` непрерывно модифицируется.

Как организовать доступ к классами `Library` из `Project1` и `Project2`?

Comment: Вы имеете в виду модульность? Или отношение Родитель-дочерний проект? Не особо понятно. Если Library только библиотека, то используйте ее как dependency. В моменты ее обновления, в ваших проектах должны будут становиться доступны новые классы

Comment: @Dred, Честно говоря. сам даже  и не знаю, что значит *в контексте Java и Maven* означает "модульность" и " родитель-дочерний проект".  Однако, "родитель-дочерний проект" звучит так, как будто директория одиного проекта находится внутри директории другого. Этот вариант мы в данном вопросе не рассматриваем .

Comment: Родительский проект и дочерний - это значит что у вас есть главный pom в котором прописаны некие зависимости. Есть дочерние проекты, которые наследуют зависимости от главного pom, а также можно добавлять свои. [пример](https://www.apache-maven.ru/advanced/inheritance.html). Под многомодульностью я это и имел в виду. А вообще, почему вы в оба своих проекта не можете указать вам Library как зависимость? типа `<dependencies><dependency><groupId>com.my</groupId><artifactId>Library</artifactId><version>1.0</version></dependency></dependencies>` ?

Comment: @Dred, тогда родительский и дочерний проект - не то. Указать как зависимсоть - это было бы замечательно, вот только не совсем понятно, как Maven найдёт эту зависимость, если она находится вне директории, где файл `pom.xml`.

Comment: По факту, вы можете вашу библиотеку использовать как jar, подкинув как library. Описано [тут](https://javadevblog.com/kak-dobavit-biblioteku-jar-fajl-v-proekt-intellij-idea.html). В таком случае, обновляете свой Library.jar после каждого изменения, а ссылку в Project1 и Project2 на него делаете не через pom, а через IDEA. После того, как проекты будут готовы, вы можете заменить зависимость из IDEA на `<dependency>` в pom. Ну, и к тому же, что вам мешает поместить всё в 1 директорию? ;)

Comment: @Dread, хорошо, тогда через IDEA. "Что вам мешает поместить всё в 1 директорию?" - в смысле несколько папкок с проектами в одну директорию?

Comment: Всё верно вам советуют. Надо библиотеку подключать как зависимость. maven найдёт её в своём локальном хранилище. А в хранилище библиотека попадёт сразу после сборки, командой install. Пример: mvn clean package install. Если разработкой занимаются несколько человек, то нужно будет поднять свой maven репозиторий. Тогда можно будет выкладывать библиотеку командой mvn deploy.

Comment: да, например по названию MyCompany, где будут лежать Libryay,Project1,Project2. Но вам уже @zuzzz подсказал тоже логичный ответ

Comment: Хорошо, благодарю всех за комментарии!